# Add new field to model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to add an external key to the model Article.New column: author.

```
   title=models.CharField(max_length=30);
    description=models.TextField();
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True);
    author=models.ForeignKey(User,default=None,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Byt after migrate I got are error:

> OperationalError at /articles/ no such column:
>   articles_article.author_id

Article list:

```
def article_list(requwest):
    articles=Article.objects.all().order_by('date')
    return render(requwest,"articles/article_list.html",{'articles':articles})
```

template:

```
<div class="articles">
        {% for article in articles %}
            <div class="article">

                <p>{{article.snipped}}</p>
                 <p>{{article.date}} </p>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

I use this lesson:[lesson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBGmqxpw0V8&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9ib4HsrXEYpQnTOTZE1x0uc&index=26)

```
After update models to:
author = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column:
>   articles_article.author_id

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: articles_article.author_id

Comment: Could you add some comments on what this does and why it solves the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
author=models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True,on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

and then run migrations.

Comment: "django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: articles_article.author_id"

Comment: Could you add some comments on what this does and why it solves the problem?

Comment: delete the migration folder and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

1)model:

```
   author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

2) Dell db.sqlite3
3) python manage.py makemigrations
4) python manage.py migrate
```